# Override landing pages tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, overriding

Landing Pages in Google Analytics is
["The pages through which visitors entered your site."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSBHH.png)

How can I override it?
For example, user go to `mydomain.com` then they go to `mydomain.com/products/product-handle`. The landing page in this case will be `/`.
Is there anyway to update landing page to `/products/product-handle` in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the reason, anyway you can to do it ending the previous session, i.e. changing source and medium.

Comment: I have tried to recreate new session and it works. Thanks :)